# CSS - Align text boxes one below another

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have the HTML code below. I am trying to align the text boxes so they line up one below the other. I have the CSS below that. Not successful. Note that the .Label and .TextBoxFor merely create and Label and Text box.

```
   <div style="text-align: left; width: 1000px"> 
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Information</legend>
      <div class="form-element-row">    
       @Html.Label("Collector")
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Collector)
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <div class="form-element-row">
       @Html.Label("Email")
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Here is the css

```
 .form-element-row
 {
    float: left;
 }

 .form-element-row label
 {
    margin: 0px;
    min-width: 400px;
 }

.form-element-row input
{
  margin: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: easier way is to use <table> instead of div's

Comment: Is that the only CSS being used on the site?  I just took what you had above (except the razor syntax) and made a fiddle, and things line up fine: http://jsfiddle.net/U4va5/

Comment: @ewitkows - Thanks The text boxes do not line up vertically though. Like them to line up vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying your forms as list items like so:

```
.form-element-row label, .form-element-row textarea {
   display: list-item;
   list-style: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use table. This way you will not have to worry about any alignments. 
You can do it like this:

```
<div style="text-align: left; width: 1000px"> 
            <fieldset>
             <legend>Information</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style ="width:30%;">
                        XXX
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="textbox"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>
                        YyYY
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="textbox"/>
                    </td>    
                </tr>
            </table>    

            </fieldset>
</div>
```